# Is using if else statement to load view based on parameters after controller and action part of url efficient or is there a better way of doing this

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I can have the following urls

```
www.example.com/accounts/
www.example.com/accounts/signup
www.example.com/accounts/signup/validate
www.example.com/accounts/login
```

for each case, accounts becomes my controller, and index, signup, signup and login becomes my actions (or methods) respectively. I have to render different views based on what my actions are. Here is an example of what my code looks like

**index**

```
$url_segments = explode('/', $url);

$controller = !empty($url_segments[0]) ? $url_segments[0] : 'home';
array_shift($url_segments); // removes the controller name from array
$action = isset($url_segments[0]) && !empty($url_segments[0]) ? $url_segments[0] : 'index';
array_shift($url_segments); // removes the action name from array

$controller = ucfirst($controller);
$controller = new $controller($url_segments);
$controller->$action();
```

**controller class**

```
class Accounts{
    private $url_segments;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->url_segments = $url_segments;
    }
    public function index() {
        // index code here
    }
    public function login() {
        // login code here
    }
    public function signup() {
        if (!isset($this->url_segments[0])) { 
            // url entered was: example.com/signup
        } else if (isset($this->url_segments[0]) && $this->url_segments[0] == 'validate') {
            // url entered was: example.com/signup/validate
        }
    }
}
```

from how my code appeared above, it can be seen that as parameters keep adding after the controller and action part of the url I'll need to keep using conditional statements to run the proper code as in the case of `/signup/` and `signup/validate`. Is this method of using conditional statement to load view based on parameters efficient or is there a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to make use of a routing system like [Symfony Routing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html). There you could add a new Route for every url and redirect them to your specific controller.
Example Route:

```
$routes = new RouteCollection();

$routes->add('/accounts_signup', route('POST', "/accounts/signup", 'App\Controller\AccountController:signup'));

return $routes;
```

This route would call the `signup` method in the AccountController calss when www.example.com/accounts/signup get called with a post request.

I recommend you to use something like this. Even if this might be a bit complicated for the beginning, after reading (and understanding) the docs this will safe you a lot of time and it will make your code more readable as well.

Comment: I get how it will work for `/signup` but I what if the url is something like this /signup/validate` would I have to reroute it to a separate method like this  `$routes->add('/accounts_signup', route('POST', "/accounts/signup/validate", 'App\Controller\AccountController:validateSignup'));`

Comment: You could also route multiple routes to the same controller. But if these two urls should not do the same, you should use an other method. And your route wouldn't work if you would use it together with mine. You would have to change `'/accounts_signup'` to something different. This is the route name and has to be unique.

Comment: Sorry for the troubles again, let me use another example, consider the urls `/products/manage/`, `/products/manage/add`, `/products/manage/delete`, if i got you correctly @Tekk even though they point to the same controller and methods (`Products::manage()` ) its okay to remap them to use different methods on the same controller eg `Products::index()`, `Products::add()`, `Products::delete()` respectively

Comment: There are multiple standards to do so. One uses a new controller for every action, the other would do it like in your example. I recommend the last one, so you wont get an overload of classes.